# File system error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, filesystem, music, fsck

I get the following error when trying to open the "Music" folder on my Mp3 player when the device is connected:

"Failed to open directory "Music" -- Error when getting information for file '/media/rory/M5/Music/Emperor - Wrath Of The Tyrant': Input/output error".

(Sometimes it shows a directory to a different song or album).

When I connect the Mp3 player and type fsck in Terminal, this is what I get:

WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.

What can I do in this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "When I connect the Mp3 player " You have an mp3 player with ext formatted filesystem?! I really doubt it. fsck is NOT the answer. You either got a faulty flashdrive in the MP3 player or a broken filesystem on the mp3. and that is more likely exFat.

Comment: I doubt the player is ext formatted. It worked fine until now, that I've started getting that error message. Am I screwed? Or is there anything I can do?

Comment: Now I get a message saying "read-only filesystem" when trying to move files to my Mp3 player

Comment: exfat-fuse has no fsck implementation.  If you're using exfat, fix it by Windows.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like the drive in the MP3 player is going bad. I've seen this exact thing multiple times on various computers and devices where I work, and every single time it's been a failing drive. As the drive gets worse and worse it will eventually start intermittently showing up as read-only, exactly as you've described.

Unfortunately, it's probably time for you to get a new MP3 player. You can try to unmount the drive and fsck the drive, but most likely it will either fail or it will "fix" some errors only to have more errors appear.